# JScrollPane Plugin - Reinitialize on Collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, accordion, jscrollpane

I'm trying to get JScrollPane to reinitialize on expand/collapse of my accordion found [here](http://igcstonedev.hingeweb.com/). You can demo the accordion by clicking on one of the parents (Stone Tiles, Stone Sinks, Stone Wall Clading, etc).

Right now I set it as a click event using the following JQuery...

```
var pane = $('.menuwrap')
pane.jScrollPane();
var api = pane.data('jsp');
var i = 1;

$("ul#widget-collapscat-5-top > li.collapsing").click(function() {
    $(this).delay(3000);
    api.reinitialise();
});
```

It seems to work when you click the parent the second time, but not the first. I have no idea why but I went into trying to edit the JS for the accordion so that I can add this function when the collapse is complete (as opposed to trying to do this click workaround). The collapse JS can be viewed [here](http://pasteit.com/18828).

I tried to add the JS for the reinitialize function here, but I think I'm not doing something properly.

May you point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `api.reinitialise()` is working properly. What is happening is that it updates the size when you click, and at this moment the element is not expanded yet. You may notice that if you expand, colapse and expand again the same section, nothing happens. But if you expand one and then click another one, the ScrollPane will adjust to the size of the first expanded element.

You can solve this with events: place `$(this).trigger('colapseComplete')` when the colapse ends. Then you can use:

```
//Listening to the colapseComplete event we triggered above
$("#widget-collapscat-5-top > li.collapsing").on('colapseComplete', function() {
  api.reinitialise();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can alter the `addExpandCollapse` function to call the `reinitialise` function at the end of each of its click actions this way :

```
function addExpandCollapse(id, expandSym, collapseSym, accordion) {
  jQuery('#' + id + ' .expand').live('click', function() {
    if (accordion==1) {
      var theDiv = jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('span.collapse').parent().find('div');
      jQuery(theDiv).hide('normal');
      jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('span.collapse').removeClass('collapse').addClass('expand');
        createCookie(theDiv.attr('id'), 0, 7);
    }
    jQuery('#' + id + ' .expand .sym').html(expandSym);
    expandCat(this, expandSym, collapseSym);

    api.reinitialise(); // HERE

    return false;
  });
  jQuery('#' + id + ' .collapse').live('click', function() {
    collapseCat(this, expandSym, collapseSym);

    api.reinitialise(); // and HERE

    return false;
  });
}
```

and to be on a safer side, make sure you have the `var api = pane.data('jsp');` line before the above piece of code anywhere in the file.